# CKEditor 4.5 drag and drop image upload - how to return new dimensions in json response?

Tags: ckeditor

I have drag and drop image uploads working using CKEditor 4.5.1. Very nice feature! On the server side I am resizing large images. My JSON response returns the resized image url (set by 'url' in the response) and that is the image that is shown in the CKEditor window after the successful file upload. But the img tag inserted has the height and width attributes set with the values from the original image, not my resized image. Is there a way to return the new height and width values? Or does anyone have an idea of how to hack around this?

And more generally, is there any resource which describes all possible values in the JSON response? I saw it mentioned somewhere that it wasn't documented yet but hopefully someone might know and take the time to share.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When uploading an image finishes, CKEditor replaces an upload widget (which contains an image with Base64 data in the source) with the final HTML. The uploaded image has the same dimensions as the one being uploaded to prevent from blinking during this replacement. [Here are the lines](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/blob/a513a92/plugins/uploadimage/plugin.js#L60-L62) that do this replacement.

If blinking when an image is uploaded is not a problem for you, then you can simple overwrite this method:

```js
editor.on( 'instanceReady', function() {
    editor.widgets.registered.uploadimage.onUploaded = function ( upload ) {
        this.replaceWith( '<img src="' + upload.url + '">' );
    }
} );
```

Now, where can we get the image dimensions from?

One option is to load the image (`upload.url`) and read its dimensions in the browser. However, this is an asynchronous operation, so it may affect the undo manager and I would not recommend it.

Therefore, if you know the new dimensions you can send then in the server response. If you put them in your JSON response like this:

```js
{
    "uploaded": 1,
    "fileName": "foo.jpg",
    "url": "/files/foo.jpg",
    "width:" 300,
    "height:" 200
}
```

You need to handle them in the response (we'll most likely simplify this bit soon):

```js
editor.on( 'fileUploadResponse', function( evt ) {
    var fileLoader = evt.data.fileLoader,
        xhr = fileLoader.xhr,
        data = evt.data;

    try {
        var response = JSON.parse( xhr.responseText );

        // Error message does not need to mean that upload finished unsuccessfully.
        // It could mean that ex. file name was changes during upload due to naming collision.
        if ( response.error && response.error.message ) {
            data.message = response.error.message;
        }

        // But !uploaded means error.
        if ( !response.uploaded ) {
            evt.cancel();
        } else {
            data.fileName = response.fileName;
            data.url = response.url;
            data.width = response.width;
            data.height = response.height;

            // Do not call the default listener.
            evt.stop();
        }
    } catch ( err ) {
        // Response parsing error.
        data.message = fileLoader.lang.filetools.responseError;
        window.console && window.console.log( xhr.responseText );

        evt.cancel();
    }
} );
```

To learn more check the [`editor#fileUploadResponse`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-event-fileUploadResponse) event and the [Uploading Dropped or Pasted Files](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_file_upload) guide.

Then you can use them in the upload widget:

```js
editor.on( 'instanceReady', function() {
    editor.widgets.registered.uploadimage.onUploaded = function( upload ) {
        this.replaceWith( '<img src="' + upload.url + '" ' +
            'width="' + upload.width + '" ' +
            'height="' + upload.height + '">' );
    }
} );
```

PS. We were considering including such a feature in the core, but because the release was huge we had to limit it at some point to bring it finally to life. There is a great chance that such a feature will be included in the core soon, and only configuration will be needed.

Comment: event better, if you want to make this behaviour as default, you can instead of doing editor.on..., change the onUploaded function in uploadimage/plugin.js.

Comment: @alexs not recommended, as you would have to potentially re-implement it every time you upgrade CKEditor to a new version.

Comment: I had to modify this code to get it to work. E.g., `editor.on( 'instanceReady', function() {`, I had to supply a param and use that internally, like `.on( 'instanceReady', function(E) {
    E.editor.widgets.` ...

Comment: I used imageupload plugin for image upload in ck editor. and implemented as mentioned above. but after upload the image it cannot resize. can you tell me are there any reasons for it

Comment: `width` and `height` are in `upload.responseData`, i.e. `upload.responseData.width` and `upload.responseData.height`. Other than that the code works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

@Michael , thanks for answer. I yet tested and can say that fileUploadResponse is not required.

Responce data can be reach from instanceReady like this (if present in responce from server ofcource)

```
__ckeditor.on( 'instanceReady', function() {
    __ckeditor.widgets.registered.uploadimage.onUploaded = function( upload ) {
        console.log(upload);
        this.replaceWith( '<img src="' + upload.url + '" ' +
            'width="' + upload.responseData.width + '" ' +
            'height="' + upload.responseData.height + '">' );
    }
} );
```