# CKEditor - drag and drop image into captioned image

Tags: javascript, image, upload, drag-and-drop, ckeditor

I am using the drag and drop feature from CKEditor 4.5 and it's really cool but when the image is successfully uploaded, it doesn't appear as I would like to.
I would like the image to directly appear as a captioned image from the enhanced image plugin, without having to double click on the image and select captioned image.

I have seen this answer [CKEditor 4.5 drag and drop image upload - how to return new dimensions in json response?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31192213/ckeditor-4-5-drag-and-drop-image-upload-how-to-return-new-dimensions-in-json-r) but I would like to know if we could precise a widget in the JSon response so the image will be formatted like we want.

Or, like in the answer linked above, should I overwrite the onUploaded to match the format of a captioned image?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can overwrite `onUploaded` like this:

```
editor.on( 'instanceReady', function() {
    editor.widgets.registered.uploadimage.onUploaded = function( upload ) {
        this.replaceWith( '<figure class="image">' +
            '<img src="' + upload.url + '" ' +
            'width="' + this.parts.img.$.naturalWidth + '" ' +
            'height="' + this.parts.img.$.naturalHeight + '">' +
            '<figcaption>Your caption</figcaption>' +
            '</figure>' );
    };
} );
```

`onUploaded` with `replaceWith` is nothing more then the HTML string which should be pasted when the upload is done. Because there are too many ways to cover all of them with the config options, the best way is to replace that string to fit your needs.

If you want to have a caption during the uploading too, you can also overwrite `fileToElement` method.